# sqlite3_exec()! = SQLITE3_OK. Trying to tranfer in OOP won't work

Tags: c++, oop, sqlite

I'm trying to work with a database in C++. I made a  program that opens the database and then creates the tables in procedural programming.
When trying to make it in OOP, `sqlite3_exec() != SQLITE_OK`

I am new at this, so be gentle.

Here is main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "sqlite3.h"
#include "Table.h"
using namespace std;

int openDatabase(sqlite3 *db);

int main() {
    sqlite3 *db;
    string columnValues, rowValues;   // these are for query
    Table Personal;
    Personal.SettableName("PERSONAL");
    columnValues = "NUME TEXT, ID TEXT";   // this is just an example

    openDatabase(db);

    Personal.createTable(db, columnValues);
    sqlite3_close(db);
    return 0;
}
```

Table.cpp

```
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "Table.h"
#include "sqlite3.h"

using namespace std;

static int callback(void *data, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName) {
    int i;
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: ", (const char*)data);

    for(i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        printf("%s = %s\n", azColName[i], argv[i] ? argv[i] : "NULL");
    }

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}

void executeSqlStatement(sqlite3 *db,const char* sql) {
    int rc = 0 ;
    char *zErrMsg = 0;

    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, 0, &zErrMsg);  // Here it doesn't work, rc=21;
    if( rc != SQLITE_OK ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
        sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
    } 
    else {
        fprintf(stdout, "Operation done successfully\n");
    }
}

void Table::createTable(sqlite3 *db, string columnDetails) {
    this->sqlCommand =  "CREATE TABLE ";

    this->sqlCommand += (this->tableName + " (" + columnDetails + ");");
    executeSqlStatement(db, this->sqlCommand.c_str());
    printf(sqlCommand.c_str());
}
```

And Table.h

```
#include "sqlite3.h"
using namespace std;
void executeSqlStatement(sqlite3 *db);
static int callback(void *data, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName);
class Table
{
public:
    void SettableName(string val){tableName = val;}
    void createTable(sqlite3 *db, string columnDetails);    
    string tableName;
    string sqlCommand;
};
```

Comment: your openDatabase() function does not write to 'db' variable scoped to "main()", could you check it?

Comment: Would it be possible that this program happens to output an error message?

Comment: It doesn't show any error.

Answer (score 0):

Including the `sqlite3.h` file in all three files is not necessary, as `Table.h` was included by both the cpp files, so you only needed to have it in that file.

The sqlite3.h file is also a system file, so using `include <sqlite3.h>` instead of `include "sqlite3.h"` makes it clearer where the file is coming from.

I would recommend compiling with the `-Wall` and `-Wextra` flags - at first they appear to make loads of complaints but it is worth paying attention to the problems reported and working out how to fix them.

Table.h

```
#include <sqlite3.h>
using namespace std;
void executeSqlStatement(sqlite3 *db);
int callback(void *data, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName);
class Table
{
public:
    void SettableName(string val){tableName = val;}
    void createTable(sqlite3 *db, string columnDetails);    
    string tableName;
    string sqlCommand;
};
```

Table.cpp

```
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "Table.h"

using namespace std;

 int callback(void *data, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName) {
    int i;
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: ", (const char*)data);

    for(i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        printf("%s = %s\n", azColName[i], argv[i] ? argv[i] : "NULL");
    }

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}

void executeSqlStatement(sqlite3 *db,const char* sql) {
    int rc = 0 ;
    char *zErrMsg = 0;

    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, 0, &zErrMsg);  // Here it doesn't work, rc=21;
    if( rc != SQLITE_OK ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
        sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
    } 
    else {
        fprintf(stdout, "Operation done successfully\n");
    }
}

void Table::createTable(sqlite3 *db, string columnDetails) {
    this->sqlCommand =  "CREATE TABLE ";

    this->sqlCommand += (this->tableName + " (" + columnDetails + ");");
    executeSqlStatement(db, this->sqlCommand.c_str());
    printf(sqlCommand.c_str());
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Table.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
    sqlite3 *db;
    sqlite3_open_v2("test.db", &db, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE, NULL);
    string columnValues, rowValues;   // these are for query
    Table Personal;
    Personal.SettableName("PERSONAL");
    columnValues = "NUME TEXT, ID TEXT";   // this is just an example


    Personal.createTable(db, columnValues);
    sqlite3_close(db);
    return 0;
}
```

On my [github](https://github.com/nstoker/super-octo-winner) I have a working version of your code, with a (borrowed) makefile to pull the files together so I just have to type `make debug` to compile the code.

```
make debug && bin/debug/hello
```

will build the file, and if the compilation was successful run the executable.